# Telegram Super Group Moderation

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm looking for a telegram bot that will allow the admins or group moderators to first approve a message before the message is released to the greater group. Admins or moderators should be able to either approve or decline a message sent by a user of a group that way to keep control of messages and content of the group ?

Comment: I didn't test it. https://github.com/OriginProtocol/telegram-moderator. I saw a message in a Channel that they used a bot moderator

Answer (score 1):

Telegram is not made use of this, I think this is impossible.

You can try allow any message in group, and if admin approved, bot forward it to channel.

Comment: Yep, a forwarding bot is the only way I see this being a possibility. One could probably also build a little neat web frontend to approve messages, but this is outside the scope of this question :P

Answer (score 0):

What about scrabbling the message posted by the users so when user sends message to group other users can't read it but only admins can read it and have to type password to open and read message ?

Comment: Here is exactly what I'm looking for but in Telegram: https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2466386?hl=en